# operator overloading c == isEqual

Tags: c++

I am comparing students in lastnamefirstnameid order but somehow my overload fails it returns false value for the following main program, I print the string comp they are same, I am really confused where I am doing wrong

```
bool Student::operator==(const Student &second) {

                if(strcmp(comp,second.comp)==0){
                        return true;
                }else{
                        return false;
                }

}:


comp=new char[strlen(fName)+strlen(lName)+strlen(id)+1];
sprintf(comp,"%s%s%s",lName,fName,id);




#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include"Student.cpp"
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    Student *st=new Student("last", "first", "id", "sitand", 34, 4.0, "se", "matricDate");//=new Student();
    Student *st2=new Student("last", "first", "id", "sitand", 34, 4.0, "se", "matricDate");//=new Student();


    st->toString();
    cout<<"\nComp1:"<<st->getComp()<<"\n";
    cout<<"\nComp2:"<<st2->getComp()<<"\n";

    if(st==st2){
        cout<<"yes i got this body";
    }else{
        cout<<"DAMNNN\n";
    }

    if(strcmp(st->getComp(),st2->getComp())==0){
        cout<<"yes body!!\n";
    }

    delete st;

    return 0;
};
```

this is the output:

```
Name:first
Last Name:last
id:id
Standing:sitand
GPA:4
Date of birth:se
Matriculation Date:matricDate
Comp1:lastfirstid

Comp2:lastfirstid
DAMNNN
yes body!!
```

Comment: Of course you are leaking memory. Why are you using `new` there?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(st==st2){
```

You compare pointers not values, so overloaded == is not called. In your case use:
    if(*st == *st2) {

Answer (score 0):

```
change `if(st==st2){` to `if(*st == *st2){`.
```

`if(*st == *st2){` will call function `bool Student::operator==(const Student &second) {`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(*st==*st2){
        cout<<"yes i got this body";
    }else{
        cout<<"DAMNNN\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `if (st == st2)` you are comparing pointers. That `if` is never going to be evaluated to true. What you actually need to do is: `if ((*st) == (*st2))`, but you can see that things are getting ugly.

First of all there's no reason to use dynamic `char` arrays, not to use `new` and `delete`. Take a look at this rewritten version instead:

```
class Student {
private:
    std::string comp;
public:
    Student(std::string last, std::string first, std::string id, ...) {
        comp = last + first + id;
    }

    operator==(const Student& second) {
        return (comp == second.comp);
    }

    // ...
};

int main(int, char*[]) {

    Student st("last", "first", "id", "sitand", 34, 4.0, "se", "matricDate");
    Student st2("last", "first", "id", "sitand", 34, 4.0, "se", "matricDate");

    std::cout << "\nComp1:"<< st.getComp()<<"\n";
    std::cout << "\nComp2:"<< st2.getComp()<<"\n";

    if (st == st2) {
        std::cout << "yes i got this body";
    } else {
        std::cout << "DAMNNN\n";
    }

    if (st.getComp() == st2.getComp())
        std::cout << "yes body!!\n";

    return 0;

}
```

Second of all, as a side effect of using `new` you are leaking the memory of `st1` (with the above code, no memory is leaked). In your specific example it doesn't matter much because at the end of the program execution the memory is claimed by the OS, but in any other part of the program it might be dangerous.